# How do I change the emulator to appear in Nexus 5 in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm doing an Android course at Udacity. I installed Android Studio and it works perfectly.

However, when I run the Nexus 5 emulator, the device appears in the image below.

[image]

Why is this device appearing?

How do I change Nexus 5 ???

Thanks!

Comment: When you created the AVD(Android Virtual Device) check the settings for Hardware Skin. Make sure you select Nexus 5

Comment: Thanks @RosárioPereiraFernandes :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select AVD Manager. As shown in the figure below:

[image]

Select show advanced settings as shown in the figure below:

[image]

Change the custom skin definition for Nexus 5 as shown in the image:

[image]

Done!!!

[image]